# showing the image file name in a input type file using image as a input file

Tags: css, reactjs, image, file, button

I  replaced the input type="file" "choose file" button with an image.Is there any way i can anyway i can show the image name while i uploaded the image.As with the css,the image name remains empty.How can i show the image name while replacing the "choose file" with an image.Here is my code:

```
                 <div>upload  file.</div>

                                <div className="image-upload">
                                    <label htmlFor="file-input">
                                        <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/mjzvuzi5b/uploader_image.png"/>
                                    </label>

                                    <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
                                </div>
                                {`
                              .image-upload > input
                            {
                               display: none;
                             }

                            .image-upload img
                            {
                            width: 80px;
                            cursor: pointer;
                            }`}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function getFileName(fName){  
  const lastDot = fName.split('\\');
  return lastDot[lastDot.length-1];
}

function App() {
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div>{fileName}</div>

           <div className="image-upload">
              <label htmlFor="file-input">
                 <img alt="a" src="https://cdn3.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/75/97/click-hand-black-simple-icon-vector-7317597.jpg"/>
              </label>   
              <input id="file-input" type="file" onChange={(e)=>{ setFileName(getFileName(e.target.value))  }} />
          </div>   
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

style.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-upload > input{
  display: none;
}

.image-upload img{
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```